# more than 2 dependent pick-lists

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, dependent-picklist

I am aiming for creating a dependency among the following pick-lists:

- **Continent**

  Europe

  Asia

  Africa
- **Country**

  Spain

  Netherlands

  China

  Korea

  Morocco
- **City**

  Madrid

  Barcelona

  Rabat

  Casablanca

  Beijing

  Macau

  Seoul

For example:

***{Europe, Asia, Africa}*** in Continent: **select** Europe: ***{Spain, Netherlands}*** in Europe: **select** Spain: ***{Madrid, Barcelona}*** in Spain: **select** **Madrid**

I tried to create one dependency on Continent and Country, where Continent is the parent, and another dependency on Country and City, where the parent is Country. However, the values are not shown as in the example above.

Can you please advise on a simplistic approach to create the described dependency? It would be nice also if you know one app in the "Salesforce App Exchange" that can do the work.

Comment: just retrieve values for child picklist based on action,  when parent  picklist value is selected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say *However, the values are not shown as in the example above.* -- how have you implemented it? Your tag suggests it's in VF page, could you post the code that you have in VF page?